# Intellij Idea thymeleaf support

Tags: html, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have

- project with spring boot(web + thymeleaf)
- Idea 2016.3.1
- Ubuntu

And I see that I should have code completion for thymeleaf in html files but I dont have it
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/thymeleaf.html

I also tried to Under Additional Libraries and Frameworks, select the Thymeleaf check box and also Web Application check box.

but is still doesnt work(code completion for spring model attributes). Does any one have same problem?

Comment: You do have the Ultimate Edition, right?

Comment: Yes, I have ultimate edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then many users actually have this problem.

From the Jetbrains website:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738

> Unfortunately this bug is the result of multiple interdependent problems (Spring Boot autoconfig model, upgrade/extension of existing Spring MVC ), each of which needs to be adressed in order to make this fully working. We're working towards a solution for 2016.x and will make results available in Early Access Program ASAP. Thanks for your understanding.